# Customise Standard lightning Component from custom lightning component

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrolling, lightning-components

I have a custom feed filter visualforce page created with the help of [this link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.case_feed_dev.meta/case_feed_dev/case_feed_dev_guide_general_customizations.htm). And then I added the vf page in lightning component with **iframe** and in case page layout. After the page is loded main-colum scrollbar is scroled to bottom of the page. How to get the scroll bar at top after page loded.

[image: -to]

**Update:**

If i run `$('.main-col').scrollTop = 2;` from browser console scrollbar is moving to top but am not sure whare to use this jQuery.